# What does tympany mean?

Tags: meaning, loanwords

There is tympanic cavity but also intestinal tympany (distended bowel). 
I cannot see relation.

What does tympany mean?

Comment: See 1. http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/tympanites 2. http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/tympany

Comment: Early 17th century: via Latin from Greek *tumpanon* 'drum'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we look at [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=tympanic&searchmode=none) it tells us about *tympanic*:

> 1808, from tympanum + -ic.

Lookin at tympanum, we find:

> "drum of the ear," 1610s, from Medieval Latin tympanum, introduced in this sense by Italian anatomist Gabriello Fallopio (1523-1562), from Latin tympanum "a drum, timbrel, tambourine," from Greek tympanon "a kettledrum," from root of typtein "to beat, strike" (see type (n.)). Compare Old English timpan "drum, timbrel, tambourine," from Latin tympanum. The modern meaning "a drum" is attested in English from 1670s.

So, it has something to do with *drums*.

Tympanic cavity is explained by [MedicineNet](http://www.medicinenet.com/script/main/art.asp?articlekey=33108) as follows:

> Tympanic cavity: The major portion of the middle ear, consisting of a narrow air-filled cavity in the temporal bone that contains the bones of the middle ear.

So it's a cavity behind the *eardrum*.

If we look at the same source for *tympany*, we find this:

> Tympany: A hollow drum-like sound that is produced when a gas-containing cavity is tapped sharply. Tympany is heard if the chest contains free air (pneumothorax) or the abdomen is distended with gas. Also known as tympanites.

So it seems that *tympany* refers to a *symptom* of what you call a distended bowel: when we hit it, it sounds *like a drum*.

Comment: +'1 Nice answer: "In addition to detection of ascites, percussion can be used to help define the nature of an abdominal mass. Tympany of an abdominal mass implies that it is gas filled (i.e., intestine)." http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK420/

Comment: @Josh61 Ah, I see :)

Comment: Excellent answer with appropriate explanation! Thank you very much!